# How to read from multiple excel sheet and merge the data based on column A

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have n number of excel files with some client# and number of hours spent on different phases of it like Installations, Troubleshooting, Delivery etc.

Client#, Installations, Troubleshooting, Delivery 
7890           2                                         1                              0.5

Similar to this I have clients in other excel files too but there could be some repetition of clients in other files. Now I need to collate all the data in one sheet but i need not to repeat the clients but sumup all the total hours in appropriate column.

I tried following code to for cloumn A to get unique clients but it didn't worked :

```
Sub Combine_Workbooks_Select_Files()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim FName As Variant

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    SaveDriveDir = CurDir
    ChDirNet "C:\"

    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
                                        MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(FName) Then
        Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
        rnum = 1
        For Fnum = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(FName(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:A25")
                End With
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
        If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Not enough rows in the sheet. "
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A" & rnum)
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If
        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
    ChDirNet SaveDriveDir

End Sub
```

Comment: "I tried following code to for cloumn A to get unique clients but it didn't worked" -> what didn't work? have you stepped through code line by line to see what is not working? Please be more specific and we can help you a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the data you want to de-dup into a known range, then you can use `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$22").RemoveDuplicates` to remove any duplicates

Comment: Now, I'm done with my above problem statement. I have a scenario now where in my sheet I may have same clients with specific hours in same phase eg. 7658 has spent 5 hours in installation another 7658 is there in excel who has also spent 3 hours in installation phase only. Now I need to add up the installation hours and remove the one client entry from the sheet. I'm not able to think on it as I have many cloumns and i have to match client with hours spent on same phase and sum up it. Any help or guidance on this.

Comment: copy the client list to a new sheet (and status, if you need to total the status hours separately).  Use the `RemoveDuplicates`, then you can change the formula of the totals cell to be a `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` - add them together to gather the data from different sheets